# Dynamically loading a content in <div> no longer working jquery. Raw new line deprecated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, codeigniter, google-chrome

I am trying to dynamically load an HTML content in a `<div>`

```
var fsearch = function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
   $.post("index.php/employee/search").done(function(res) {
      alert(res);
      $("#emp_list").load(res);
   });
};
$("#search_box").submit(fsearch);
```

I am running this on Chrome. However it seems this is no longer possible. The console says

```
[Deprecation] Resource requests whose URLs contain raw newline characters 
are deprecated, and may be blocked in M60, around August 2017. Please remove
newlines from places like element attribute values in order to continue
loading those resources. See
https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5735596811091968 for more details.
```

I am using codeIgniter for the development

Is there another way on how to achieve my objective?

Comment: try $("#emp_list").html(res); //instead of load, load send request to the server ..  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: As @Farzam Babar said you need .html instead of .load. Your res object is the HTML that is returned to you that you need to populate in the div, .load expects an URL as first parameter so when u call it with passing the response  it tries to make a request to some address like 'http://<div>some stuff</div>' which is of course totally incorrect URL and you eventually have a new line in your HTML, and the first thing you hit is  this type of validation so you get that message instead of 'resource not found' or something similar.